Why am I getting a "LM_WRITE_LOG_FAILED ERROR 80000" in GridDB when writing to the log file?
I'm using GridDB for managing a distributed database system and recently encountered the following error while trying to perform operations:
80000 LM_WRITE_LOG_FAILED ERROR
Writing to log file failed. A failure may have occurred in the storage at the log file storage location.
Here is a simplified version of the code I'm using:
from griddb_python import GridStoreFactory, StoreFactory
import os
import shutil

def check_disk_space(path):
    total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage(path)
    print(f"Total: {total // (2**30)} GiB")
    print(f"Used: {used // (2**30)} GiB")
    print(f"Free: {free // (2**30)} GiB")
    return free > 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024  # Ensure at least 1GB is free

def perform_griddb_operations():
    log_path = "/var/log/griddb"
    
    if not check_disk_space(log_path):
        raise Exception("Not enough disk space available for log files.")
    
    try:
        factory = StoreFactory.get_default()
        gridstore = factory.get_store({
            "host": "239.0.0.1",
            "port": 41999,
            "cluster_name": "defaultCluster",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        })

        # Attempt to get a container
        container = gridstore.get_container("containerName")
        if container is None:
            raise Exception("Container not found")

        # Perform some operations on the container
        row = container.get(1)
        print(f"Row retrieved: {row}")

        container.put(2, {"id": 2, "value": "value2"})
        print("Row inserted")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Operation failed: {e}")
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    perform_griddb_operations()


Despite ensuring there is enough disk space, I frequently encounter the LM_WRITE_LOG_FAILED ERROR 80000. This error suggests a failure in writing to the log file, potentially due to storage issues.
Here are some additional details about my setup:
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Python Version: 3.8
GridDB Version: 4.5
Cluster Size: 5 nodes
Log File Path: /var/log/griddb
I'm looking for guidance on:
Common causes of the LM_WRITE_LOG_FAILED ERROR 80000.
Best practices for managing log file storage in GridDB.
Any additional checks or diagnostics I should perform to identify the root cause of this issue.
Has anyone experienced similar issues with GridDB, or can anyone provide insights into what might be going wrong?
